# Deep linking in wechat

Tags: deep-linking, wechat, weixinjsbridge

Is it possible to implement deep linking with wechat API ? I am using wechat API to share some content through WeChat sharing. I have registered my app with wechat and can authenticate users. How would I be able to open my app from Wechat on clicking on that Link? I tried to send the myapp:// as link but wechat does not open my app the safari or facebook does.

Answer (score 3):

Wechat seems to actively prevent deep linking to most external applications. I suspect this is a strategy to prevent sites from using Wechat as a channel to bring users into competing applications.

There are a couple of things that you could try: If your audience is in China, then hosting your app on app.qq.com (which is a Tencent property) will either take you on to the App Store for iOS, or install and run your app through the YingYongBao application on Android.

Take a look at the NikeRunClub service account for an example of this, (Left hand menu -> 必备APP下载)

A second approach is to link to a second page and instruct the user to open that page in their native browser. When the page is re-opened detect that the user agent is not "MicroMessenger" and then redirect to the your original protocol link.

Comment: Thanks, I am developing an iOS app for Chinese Audience. I was already thinking about the second approach.  Could you please tell me if I host my app on app.qq.com will wechat allow to redirect to my app ? (of course if it's insalled). How can I host app on app.qq.com ?

Comment: Hello @AsadullahAli did you find any workaround to open specific profile from ios app ? i have been stuck in this issue , could you please share !

Comment: @dip did you find a solution for opening a wechat profile with deep linking?